# React Native crashing in Android and getting Signal 11 error in console. Iam using react-native: 0.37.0

Tags: android, react-native

I am using ScrollView for News feed posts rendering and it is crashing most of the times in feed page only.

Error:

> ```
> signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR)
> _ZN3JSC8JSObject13visitChildrenEPNS_6JSCellERNS_11SlotVisitorE
> ```

This is the Full trace of the crash:

```
    backtrace:
  native: pc 000000000012659a  /data/app/com.cowrksconnect-2/lib/arm/libjsc.so (_ZN3JSC8JSObject13visitChildrenEPNS_6JSCellERNS_11SlotVisitorE+213)
  native: pc 00000000000753f5  /data/app/com.cowrksconnect-2/lib/arm/libjsc.so
  native: pc 0000000000071855  /data/app/com.cowrksconnect-2/lib/arm/libjsc.so
  native: pc 0000000000071dd3  /data/app/com.cowrksconnect-2/lib/arm/libjsc.so (_ZN3JSC4Heap7collectENS_13HeapOperationE+274)
  native: pc 000000000003afbf  /data/app/com.cowrksconnect-2/lib/arm/libjsc.so
  native: pc 0000000000073c8b  /data/app/com.cowrksconnect-2/lib/arm/libjsc.so (_ZN3JSC15MarkedAllocator16allocateSlowCaseEj+90)
  native: pc 000000000009aa2b  /data/app/com.cowrksconnect-2/lib/arm/libjsc.so
  native: pc 00000000000015e1  <unknown>
```